# How to use customized namespace and its property in other ts files

Tags: typescript

I start to construct an application with typescript, and run into a concept problem. I defined a namespace which includes several properties and functions, now i want to use these functions in other files. The problem is how i can include the namespace;

[image][image]

As the pictures above, the namespace 'Cat' is not defined.

i have tried "put a 'export' before word 'namespace', and import it as a common module in my file". However, i don't think that is the right way how 'namespace work' , cause it makes the namespace like a 'module'.

So, is there anyone who can tell me a graceful way that namespace work;

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to put a reference to your file containing the namespace at the top of your file:

`///<reference path="./Cat.ts" />`

See the TypeScript documentation on splitting namespaces across files: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#splitting-across-files